# Do we want / need a tag for player companions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Multiple games have a concept of a non-player-character escorting the player's character and helping him or her in some way, e.g. the companions in Skyrim or the followers in Diablo III.

Right now we have [npcs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/npcs), which in my eyes is way too wide and not really useful, close to a "monsters" tag. [npcs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/npcs) is used on some companion-related Skyrim questions.

My question is, should we have a separate tag, called "companions" or "followers", dedicated to these NPCs which escort the player character and help? Some users seem interested in one, and I personally think it can be a good idea - it's probably useful for games like the aforementioned ones. Opinions?

Comment: I've dithered on this issue repeatedly, but honestly, at this point, until we can get our tagging house in order, I'm back to being of the opinion that we really don't need anything other than [game-title] with a very small subset of exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I guess the answer to the question in the title is "we don' need it, we don' wan' it!"